# Refresh data on button click react

Tags: reactjs

I tried to build a refresh button to refresh my react-table data, here is my code

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
const [refreshData, setRefreshData] = useState(false);

const getData = async ()=>{
 const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/in-data')
 setData(response.data)
 setLoadingData(false);
}

useEffect(()=>{
 getData()
},[refreshData])
```

Here is the button

```
<button
  className="button"
  type="button"
  onClick={setRefreshData(!RefreshData)}         
>
  Refresh
</button>
```

The result is Error: Infinite Looping, reach the maximum number of re-render. Anyone know how to do it in the proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is executing the function *immediately*, not on button click:

```
onClick={setRefreshData(!RefreshData)}
```

The *result* of the function would then be set as the click handler, but since that result is causing a re-render then that point is moot.

You want to pass a function reference as the click handler, not the execution of a function (unless that execution returns the function reference you want, of course).  Something like this:

```
onClick={() => setRefreshData(!RefreshData)}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try please putting your function inside of useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
const getData = async ()=>{
 const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/in-data')
 setData(response.data)
 setLoadingData(false);
}
if(refreshData){
   getData()
}
},[refreshData])
```

click on button

```
onClick={() => setRefreshData(!RefreshData)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that clicking the "refresh" button is supposed to reload the data for the page. So you should do that! In other words, instead of your current approach, you should add a click handler to the button that cals `getData()` to fetch the data. `refreshData` and `setRefreshData()` aren't needed:

```
<button
  className="button"
  type="button"
  onClick={getData}         
>
```